# Htaccess is causing bad flag delimeters

Tags: .htaccess

i'm receiving error 500 and i checked the error log in apache i get bad flag delimeters.
Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA, L]
```

Comment: Did you notice the space betweent **QSA** and **L** ?

Comment: Thanks, Finally it works. I use to put space after every comma for readability. didn't know such things matters in .htaccess files.